# Elasticsearch agg filter using an array of values

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{ "colors":["red","black","blue"] }
{ "colors":["red","black"] }
{ "colors":["red"] }
{ "colors":["orange, green"] }
{ "colors":["purple"] }
```

How can I run an agg that filters for specific values contained in the array field?
For example, I only want the count of "red" and wish to exclude its other siblings from the aggregation result.

Note: I cannot use an "include" pattern for "red".  This example is simplistic, the real-world example has a long list of string values that are unique.

I would like to filter the agg using an array of string values.

Comment: Are you trying to filter the documents that are used for the aggregation or instead do you want to filter the values that *appear* on the aggregation result?  Can you be a bit more clean please.

Comment: I want to do both: 1) filter the documents, 2) filter the values that appear on the aggregation result.  So the first filter would remove the last 2 rows (using the example above).  The second filter would just give me "red" and it's aggregate count.  Note as I stated before, the second filter will be an array of values to match against.

Comment: "include" can take an array of values. Beyond this I don't see it to be possible

Comment: @jaspreetchahal  I didn't realize that "include" can use an array of values.  This solves the problem!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_exact_values_2)

> For matching based on exact values the include and exclude parameters can simply take an array of strings that represent the terms as they are found in the index:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "colors": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "colors",
        "include": [ "red","black" ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```